# HTML EMail Template

Tags: html, email, templates

Anybody knows where I can find nice HTML Templates to send email reports?

Edit : Moved here http://doctype.com/html-email-template

Comment: I think this might be best migrated to Superuser.

Comment: I'm thinking that wouldn't be smart for someone without beta acces.

Comment: @WebDevHobo, ..ah, that'd be true =)

Comment: I just noticed at the bottom of the page the site doctype.com, I will move/post this question there.

Comment: It looks like it is a different system :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know what kind of reports you're interested in, but I'd go for [Campaign Monitor's templates](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/templates/) just to make sure they're tested in all email clients. With those you can rest assured that most of your users will get exactly what you're seeing. From the zip file that comes with each template, use the "example" folder.

Comment: Yes, I saw those but those looks like sale newsletters. I'm looking for something more "IT style"

Answer (score 5):

keys to remember before working html email template

> - Always follow table layout to look decent on cross platform.
> - Media query and too much HTML tags and CSS are are not supported cross platform. So better to go for tested HTML/CSS tags.
> - Try to use inline CSS.
> - It's better to check how does your email look on several devices and platforms.
> - It should look decent even if no image is there because some provider blocks the image or ask user to download it manually
> - Put appropriate alternate text for image for the same reason.

here are some template 
I had put for you.
[gitHub url for html email template](https://github.com/app4pc/html-email-bible)

Answer (score 0):

1. HTML e-mail is evil :)
2. HTML support for some e-mail clients lags by a lot. I would go with very simple designs, definitely nothing off a vanilla website template collection.

Comment: I know about poor HTML support in some email clients but I don't care.This is gonna be just for internal notifications...

Comment: For example Linkedin email notifications are simple, but I want something more "eye caching". For those who knows "mint.com" I would like something similar - it is a piece of light green paper with the corners lift up(visual effect).